# MongoDB/Mongoose - Find all where a specific Date is in a Date Range

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

for example I have documents with this field:

```
startDate: 2021-04-14T22:00:00.000+00:00
endDate: 2021-04-19T22:00:00.000+00:00
```

and I want to get all documents where a specific date (like today) is in the date range.
Is it possible to make such a query?
For example if I search for 18th April, then I get that document.

I thought something like this:

```
db.posts.find(
{
 $gte: { startDate: new Date() },
 $lt: { endDate: new Date() }
});
```

But this doesn't work... I get an error `The provided parameters were invalid. Check your query and try again.`

I think new Date() is not correct in Node.js?

EDIT:

This is my Controller:

```
const getActiveTours = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const activeTours = await Tour.find({
      startDate: { $gte: new Date() },
      endDate: { $lt: new Date() },
    }).exec();
    res.status(200).send(activeTours);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: error });
  }
};
```

I exported it and here is my endpoint:

```
router.get('/getactivetours', tourController.getActiveTours);
```

I tried to call this in Postman but get an empty [] back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, try this one:

```
db.posts.find(
{
 startDate: {$gte : new Date() },
 endDate: {$lt : new Date() }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! At least I don't get any error now but an empty [] seems it could not find any

Comment: Are `startDate` and `endDate` values `Date` objects or are they stored as strings?

Comment: Okay, I did a mistake! gotta swap gte and lt for start and end date!! It works now Thanks a lot